# Arch linux randomly freezes after updating to kernel 5.10

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, package-management, freeze, journalctl

last three days I am experiencing random freezes. If i am looking on youtube when this happens Audio keeps playing but screen is froze and keyboard or cursor do not do anything.

I trying to look in `sudo journalctl` and this is what I found:

```
led 04 10:44:02 arch-thinkpad kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=113031 end=113032) time 340 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1062, end 1085
led 04 11:09:15 arch-thinkpad kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=203838 end=203839) time 273 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1072, end 1090
led 04 11:15:47 arch-thinkpad kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=227329 end=227330) time 278 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1066, end 1085
```

`uname -a` returns:

```
Linux arch-thinkpad 5.10.4-arch2-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri, 01 Jan 2021 05:29:53 +0000 x86\_64 GNU/Linux
```

I use: i3wm, picom, pulseaudio. I have lenovo x390 yoga with intel processor.

How can I diagnose and solve this problem?

---

**EDIT:** Upgrading linux kernel to 5.10.16 solved my problem. Still I will accept answer of @Sylvain POULAIN for its complex view on the problemand offering alternative solution.

Comment: For me, it was also solved on NixOS by upgrading to a newer kernel (5.12 in my case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5.10.15 doesn't solve this problem. I still have same error. Intel bugs are really annoying since kernel > 4.19.85 (November 2019 !)

As a workaround, i915 guc need to be enable as mentionned in Archlinux Wiki : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Enable_GuC_/_HuC_firmware_loading and loaded before others modules

To resume :

1. Add guc paramters to kernel parameters by editing `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.enable_guc=2"
```

2. Add guc option to i915 module by adding `/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf` file with :

```
options i915 enable_guc=2
```

3. Add i915 to `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` :

```
MODULES=(i915)
```

4. Rebuild kernel initramfs (needs reboot after successfull build) :

```
# mkinitcpio -P
```

5. Remove xf86-video-intel (driver is already in kernel) :

```
# pacman -Rscn xf86-video-intel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What should I when I do use systemd boot instead of grub ?

Comment: So far, 5.10.15 did solve my problem... 4 days without crash so far.

Comment: There was an error with contents of /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf, I have updated it. Consider removing xf86-video-intel package, if you have it installed, as more recent modules are already packed in kernel ... 

@JanČerný you should edit loader conf, it's well described in archlinux wiki

Comment: And that, people, is why you don't use or suggest rolling release or fast-paced (less than 2 years cycle) distributions to beginners or if you do serious works that uses "stale" software anyway. There's too much of these kind of "suggestions" and "my update broke something (like Windows 10)" on the web.

Comment: @X.LINK :
- if you have new material you need recent kernel
- you can contribute to kernel feedback
- in rolling release you could choose a stable branch kernel instead of still ... Rolling release like manjaro have better kernel management and have more options to chosse one. So your comment about rolling release doesn't make sense. For this problem in this conversation you have the thank you Intel which is the first culprit ...

Comment: If you buy very new hardware from day one, you'll likely get bugs that even newer kernels at that time won't address, yet. Same with Windows. Better wait few months later for OEM to iron things out then buy. On Ubuntu and for example the RX 6900XT, you'll get the required kernel  ( >= 5.8) and mesa ( >= 20.02) with the hardware enablement stack due in August 2021 (20.04.3). And even if you can't wait, you have the PPA way, but there won't be any buggy kernel from standard updates like in any rolling release distro. Even non LTS kernels have bad bugs since the "stable" branch don't even helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it by downgrading linux kernel. I achieved it by installing *downgrader* package using `yay`:

```
yay -S downgrader
```

Then I ran `downgrader linux` which game me list of cached versions of kernel:

```
Downgrade package: linux
1: linux-5.9.arch1-https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  [installed]
2: linux-5.9.9.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.9.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
3: linux-5.9.8.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.8.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
4: linux-5.9.7.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.7.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
5: linux-5.9.6.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.6.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
6: linux-5.9.5.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.5.arch2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
7: linux-5.9.4.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.4.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
8: linux-5.9.3.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.3.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
9: linux-5.9.2.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.2.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
10: linux-5.9.14.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.14.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
11: linux-5.9.13.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.13.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
12: linux-5.9.12.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.12.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
13: linux-5.9.11.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.11.arch2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
14: linux-5.9.11.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.11.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
15: linux-5.9.10.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.10.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
16: linux-5.9.1.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.9.1.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
17: linux-5.8.arch1-https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.arch1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
18: linux-5.8.arch1-https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
19: linux-5.8.9.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.9.arch2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
20: linux-5.8.9.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.9.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
21: linux-5.8.8.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.8.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
22: linux-5.8.7.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.7.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
23: linux-5.8.6.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.6.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
24: linux-5.8.5.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.5.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
25: linux-5.8.4.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.4.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
26: linux-5.8.3.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.3.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
27: linux-5.8.2.archhttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.2.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
28: linux-5.8.14.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.14.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
29: linux-5.8.13.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.13.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
30: linux-5.8.12.archttps://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/linux-5.8.12.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  (from ALA)
```

I chosed the first one, proceed to install and `sudo reboot`. Now when I run `uname -a` i get:

```
Linux arch-thinkpad 5.9.0-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon, 12 Oct 2020 18:52:13 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

I have not experience any freezes since downgrade. If anything happens or I will get better diagnostics of issue I will update this answer.

EDIT: upgrading to 5.10.16 solved the issue

Comment: same issue here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629128/os-freezes-completely/632657#632657
looks like 5.10.15 might fix this issue once released