# OS freezes completely

Tags: arch-linux, kernel, freeze

Since yesterday, I am having regular total freeze of my OS, archlinux, with no clear reason why.

The only thing I'm doing is browsing the internet with Firefox while it happens.

The audio, bluetooth are still working during these freezes, but I have no way to interact with the system...

I tried to find something helpful in the system log:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b -1 -k -xe
...
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel: INFO: task kworker/0:1H:213 blocked for more than 122 seconds.
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:       Tainted: G        W         5.10.6-arch1-1 #1
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel: task:kworker/0:1H    state:D stack:    0 pid:  213 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel: Workqueue: events_highpri intel_atomic_cleanup_work [i915]
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel: Call Trace:
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  __schedule+0x295/0x810
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  schedule+0x5b/0xc0
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x11/0x20
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  __ww_mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x4bd/0x810
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  ? dequeue_entity+0xc6/0x460
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  intel_unpin_fb_vma+0x25/0xa0 [i915]
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  drm_atomic_helper_cleanup_planes+0x52/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  intel_atomic_cleanup_work+0x67/0x110 [i915]
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  process_one_work+0x1d6/0x3a0
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3d0
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x410/0x410
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  kthread+0x133/0x150
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x60/0x60
Jan 14 10:22:45 flexywhale kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel: INFO: task kworker/0:1H:213 blocked for more than 245 seconds.
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:       Tainted: G        W         5.10.6-arch1-1 #1
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel: task:kworker/0:1H    state:D stack:    0 pid:  213 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel: Workqueue: events_highpri intel_atomic_cleanup_work [i915]
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel: Call Trace:
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  __schedule+0x295/0x810
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  schedule+0x5b/0xc0
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  schedule_preempt_disabled+0x11/0x20
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  __ww_mutex_lock.constprop.0+0x4bd/0x810
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  ? dequeue_entity+0xc6/0x460
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  intel_unpin_fb_vma+0x25/0xa0 [i915]
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  drm_atomic_helper_cleanup_planes+0x52/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  intel_atomic_cleanup_work+0x67/0x110 [i915]
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  process_one_work+0x1d6/0x3a0
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3d0
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x410/0x410
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  kthread+0x133/0x150
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  ? __kthread_bind_mask+0x60/0x60
Jan 14 10:24:48 flexywhale kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
...
```

These freezes did not occur after a system update (it was last updated about a week ago) and I updated my system since to try to fix it but without success.

What can I do to diagnose and try to resolve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the same issue that is discussed [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/2905) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262456).

A short-term solution (that works for me too) is uninstalling `xf86-video-intel`.

Comment: thanks, it looks very promising indeed. Waiting for 5.10.15 as it looks like they have fixed it there

Comment: @ogr Finally! I am waiting so long for fix of this issue.